# DNS Server (with no internet connection)

Tags: c#, dns, server

Let's say i have DNS server installed on IP : 192.168.1.25
This server has no access to internet.  Client sends query to this server for hostname "www.google.com". Can I respond to client to query another server ? How?

Comment: No access to internet means you can not get connection to other locations.  You can still have access to your local intranet.  So if two PCs are both on the same local internet that can communicate provided the routing is set up correctly.  Routing is a combination of the IP address and the mask.

Comment: Do you want to hijack DNS queries?